# mysql query to select all but limit each occurrence of parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm having a hard time wording this question.  I have a database of messages and I want to retrieve, for example, the latest 2 from each conversation.  How can I put a limit inside the query syntax to limit each unique user to just two?  Or do I have to select all and then loop inside the fetch assoc?  The query looks something like this:

```
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$lastid = $_REQUEST['lastId'];
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'messagedb');
if ($link) {
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (toName='$to' OR fromName='$to') AND id>'$lastid' order by id desc");
    $messages = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if (!in_array($row['toName'], $messages) || !in_array($row['fromName'], $messages)) {
            $messages[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that's not working...it just gets everything back...plus I can't put a limit on how many rows already in there.  I'm hoping there's a simple solutions for the query.  Thanks in advance!

The database looks something like this:

```
id  |  fromName   |   toName   |   theMessage
------------------------------------------------------------
 1        me           joe       some message to joe from me
 2        john         me        message from john to me
 3        sarah        me        message from sarah to me
 4        joe          me        answer back to joe from me
 5        me           john      answer back to john from me
 6        me           sarah     answer back to sarah from me
 //and so on...just conversations between people
```

So in my query, the $to is me, or whatever user will be using it.  I want to get my/their conversations with each person but limit it to a certain number at the start...so later they can load more.

Comment: Can you describe more accurately what you're trying to achieve ? And also (if possible) can you make a schema of the table in question ?

Comment: ok, one second.  sorry, after I posted the question I figured people would need to see how it is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (toName='$to' OR fromName='$to') AND id>'$lastid' order by id desc LIMIT number_of_rows
```

Comment: That doesn't work...it just gets back the last two rows.  What I want is the last two rows of messages from, like in my question's database, last two rows of the conversation from me and sarah, me and joe, me and john.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Copy and Paste This And Than Check..

Nothing Just you made an Error on putting `Varaibles`

```
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$lastid = $_REQUEST['lastId'];
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'messagedb');
if ($link) {
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (toName='".$to."' OR fromName='".$to."') AND id>'".$lastid."' order by id desc");
    $messages = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if (!in_array($row['toName'], $messages) || !in_array($row['fromName'], $messages)) {
            $messages[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...it's still giving me everything from the database.  How can I loop the rows and just add to $messages the last 2 entries of 'toName' or 'fromName'?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which would need attention (like the fact you're not relying on some date/time field to organize messages). Then, as you are stating, the best method would be using PHP to take the last two rows from each combination of from/to addresses.
Otherwise you could also use the [**top clause**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp), but I can hardly think of a method to achieve what you want directly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "take the last two rows from each combination of from/to addresses"?  How is that done with PHP?

Comment: The identifier for each conversation is the pair "from/to-to/from" which is unique and identify each conversation. Using that you can loop and identify each conversation, then you should only take the first two. Also I found something that may interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results